# Query with multiple filters on Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to execute this query.The query is " filtering data with 'Gas Oil/ Diesel Oil - Production' transaction and the year is greater than 2000 ". Firstly , i tried to  execute my query with  & operand and vectorized column selection without using if statement. But it did not work.After then , i found this query at below.This time  i could not get any output.What do you think about my query problem ?.Thanks ...

```
if all(b['Commodity - Transaction'] == 'Gas Oil/ Diesel Oil - Production') and all(b[ b['Year'] >2000 ]):
   print (b)
else:
    print('did not find any values')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try first create mask with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and the create subset - use [Boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print b[(b['Commodity - Transaction'].str.contains('Gas Oil/ Diesel Oil - Production'))  &  
        (b['Year'] > 2000) ]
```

Comment: btw the first set of parentheses are redundant (i wish the second were too ... operator precedence of & is a major pet peeve of mine when using pandas)

Comment: Hmmm, you are right. It can be removed, but if you check [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#building-criteria) - parentheses are using for first and second condition too.

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong with:

```
b.loc[(b['Commodity - Transaction'] == 'Gas Oil/ Diesel Oil - Production') & (b['Year'] >2000)]
```

?

Comment: I got this error   ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Sorry it is my bad.Your query works  with print statement like that print ( b.loc[(b['Commodity - Transaction'] == 'Gas Oil/ Diesel Oil - Production') & (b['Year'] >2000)] )